# Use of "of...of"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "of...of" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The novelties of present paper are investigation **of effect of** the
>   blade thickness and entropy generation on based aerodynamic and
>   entropy generation analysis.

Comment: The entire sentence does not sound grammatical to me. But it might help if you included some definite articles e.g. *The novelties of **the** present paper are **the** investigation of **the** effect of the blade thickness and entropy generation on **the** based aerodynamic and **the** entropy generation analysis.*

Comment: I think it would help if you'd gave us a simpler sentence, this seems rather scientific. The fact that not everyone (including myself) would understand what you're trying to say exactly makes it hard to properly answer the question. Also, as a general rule, try not to make sentences too long, or at least use a few commas to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that several required articles are omitted, the "of" ... "of" is fine: how else would you express it?

I don't know what the part after "thickness" is meant to mean. I suspect that "on based" should read "based one"; but I have no idea how the various sections coordinated by "and" are grouped.

> The novelties of **the** present paper are **an** investigation of **the** effect of (the) blade thickness...

Comment: Is it OK?
The novelties of the present paper are an investigation of the effect of the blade thickness based on aerodynamic and the entropy generation analysis.